# Java - Joda time List<LocalDate> find latest date

Tags: java, jodatime

following are the List of Dates by using Joda time API, i want to find the latest Date from the Below List

```
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
dates.add(eefdTewntyArray)
dates.add(rdTewntyArray);
dates.add(idSeventyArray);
```

output for the above list

```
[2025-08-01, 2025-08-01, 2026-08-01]
```

i want to choose the latest date and stored into an LocalDate, it may increase the 'n' number of date also

Comment: Use `Collections.sort`

Comment: Take a look to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877031/get-the-most-current-latest-date-object-in-list

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Will it working without passing the custom Comparator?

Comment: @TheLostMind `LocalDate` is `Comparable` (as inherited from `AbstractPartial`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I just saw that :)

Comment: If all you want is the latest date, sorting is overkill.  Use `Collections.max` instead.

Comment: @Misha Depending how "unsorted" the `List` is, sorting may be quicker, but in either case, (at worst), you'd have to visit each element in the `List`, of course, if the order is important and you don't want it modified, that would also work ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer The only possible way for sorting to be faster is if you have a specialized implementation of `List`, which *knows* that it's sorted and then `sort` is a no-op.  Otherwise, it will take at least as much time to determine that the list is sorted as it would take to find the max.

Comment: @Misha I wasn't worried about finding out if it was unsorted or not, but because the sort is using a form of mergesort, it wouldn't have to always visit ALL the elements, where are `max` HAS not. As I said, at worse, it would be similar, not knocking your point of using `max`, but saying it's "overkill" is a little "overkill" :P

Comment: Please sort [1, 2, 5, 10, X] without knowing the value of X.  Unless you know ahead of time which parts of the list are sorted, you **must** look at each element at least once.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Collections.max` for this one.  Since each `LocalTime` implements `Comparable`, this is safe and straightforward to do.

```
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();
dates.add(new LocalDate(2025, 8, 1));
dates.add(new LocalDate(2025, 8, 1));
dates.add(new LocalDate(2026, 8, 1));

// prints "2006-08-01"
System.out.println(Collections.max(dates));
```

[`Collections#max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) runs in linear time with a worst-case performance of O(n), whereas [`Collections#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) is based on [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which has a worst-case runtime of O(n log n).  If your list of dates becomes sufficiently large, then and only then would I consider using the sort approach; here, it's a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collections.sort` to sort the list of `LocalDate`s...

```
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
dates.add(new LocalDate(2025, 8, 1));
dates.add(new LocalDate(2024, 8, 1));
dates.add(new LocalDate(2026, 8, 1));

Collections.sort(dates);

System.out.println(dates);
```

Which prints

```
[2024-08-01, 2025-08-01, 2026-08-01]
```

Now you can pick out the earliest (index `0`) or the latest (index `size() - 1`).  You can even `reverse` the `List` of it's easier

Answer (score 0):

With lambdas:

**For oldest date:**

```
dates.stream().sorted().findFirst().get()
```

**For latest date:**

```
dates.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).findFirst().get()
```