# Find Latest timestamp from DateTime class

Tags: java, datetime, time, jodatime

I have a list of `DateTime` objects and my task is to compare them and find the latest timestamp. The `DateTime` class is used from Joda API. I have been stuck on this part for a little while now. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Similar to [Java - Joda time List<LocalDate> find latest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709018/java-joda-time-listlocaldate-find-latest-date). What did *your* search turn up?

Answer (score -1):

### Collections.max()

```
    DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.forID("Indian/Comoro");
    List<DateTime> dateTimeObjects = Arrays.asList(
            new DateTime(2021, 2, 13, 21, 0, dtz),
            new DateTime(2021, 2, 13, 22, 0, dtz),
            new DateTime(2021, 2, 13, 23, 0, dtz));
    DateTime latestDateTime = Collections.max(dateTimeObjects);
    System.out.println(latestDateTime);
```

Output:

> 2021-02-13T23:00:00.000+03:00

`Collections.max()` throws a `NoSuchElementException` if the list is empty. It throws a `NullPointerException` if the list contains a `null` (except perhaps if the `null` is the sole element, then it may get returned).

When comparing `DateTime` objects *from different time zones* Joda-Time first compares the instants, the points in time, so also in this case you are getting the latest. For example:

```
    List<DateTime> dateTimeObjects = Arrays.asList(
            new DateTime(2021, 2, 13, 21, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Istanbul")),
            new DateTime(2021, 2, 13, 22, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("Atlantic/Madeira")),
            new DateTime(2021, 2, 13, 23, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("Antarctica/Macquarie")));
    DateTime latestDateTime = Collections.max(dateTimeObjects);
    System.out.println(latestDateTime);
```

Output:

> 2021-02-13T22:00:00.000Z

We got the time 22:00 for Madeira. You may wonder that the time 23:00 for Macquarie would seem later, but Macquarie is at UTC offset +11:00, so that time is in fact 10 hours earlier. `DateTime` objects are `Comparable` and compare by instant, not by clock hour. So we have got the latest point in time. We always will, also when several time zones are mixed.

**Documentation link:** [`Collections.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection))